# How to generate MetaModel for Redis Document entity to use in Redis OM EntityStream queries

Tags: java, redis, metamodel, redisearch

I use Redis OM Spring Entity Streams, which provides a Java 8 Streams interface to Query Redis JSON documents using RediSearch.

I want to generate a metamodel like Person$ to run the code below. But I couldn't figure out how to generate the metamodel for the Person document entity. Can you please help me to find out a way to generate the metamodel? Thanks in advance.

```
> // Find people by age range   public Iterable<Person>
> findByAgeBetween(int minAge, int maxAge) {
>     return entityStream //
>         .of(Person.class) //
>         .filter(Person$.AGE.between(minAge, maxAge)) //
>         .sorted(Person$.AGE, SortOrder.ASC) //
>         .collect(Collectors.toList());   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle, you can add the OM dependency as an annotation processor using the `annotationProcessor` call in the dependencies block like:

```
ext {
  redisOmVersion = '0.8.0'
}

dependencies {
  implementation: "com.redis.om:redis-om-spring:$redisOmVersion"
  annotationProcessor "com.redis.om:redis-om-spring:$redisOmVersion"
}
```

For Maven, things normally just work, when you run `./mvnw spring-boot:run`. Some users have experienced this not being the case, in which I recommend to explicitly declaring the `maven-compiler-plugin` in the case below it's pair with an app create with start.spring.io v3.0.4 (all other versions can be inherited from the parent poms):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
      </path>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      </path>
      <path>
        <groupId>com.redis.om</groupId>
        <artifactId>redis-om-spring</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also, in case you are using IntelliJ Idea, see
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html#annotation_processing

Comment: thanks for your answer @BSB . I am new to Metamodel concept, please bear with me here:) I found the metamodel classes under the folder target/generated-sources/annotations . And I moved them to src folder. After that I ran mvn clean install. And install failed due to metamodel classes. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't move them, just add that folder to your IDE's source path.

Comment: Does this work with Kotlin too?

Comment: Now it does, thanks for the assist @LucasLeón